# yii import extension not finding class

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, yii

I am using the Facebook SDK For PHP.
I added the facebook php SDk in the yii app protected/extension folder and imported it in config/main.php as follow.

```
'import' => array(
    'application.extensions.facebook.*',
),
```

my problem is that the app is not finding the classes in the sdk when i create the object as follows:

```
 $session = new FacebookSession($access_token);
```

it is giving error as follow:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FacebookSession' not found ....
```

if I try using `include_once()` or `require_once()` then it is giving error as below:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Facebook\FacebookSession in D:\localhost\protected\extensions\facebook\FacebookSession.php on line 36
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: please expose your extention folder content.

Comment: extension\facebook\FacebookSession.php
extension\facebook\FacebookResponse.php
extension\facebook\Utilities
extension\facebook\HttpClients
extension\facebook\FacebookRequest.php
and many other facebook classes

Comment: what file stands for the `FacebookSession` class? If FacebookSession.php, then you add in the import array: `'application.extensions.facebook.FacebookSession',`

Comment: i tried with application.extensions.facebook.FacebookSession also but it not works. i am getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by adding

set_include_path(Yii::app()->baseUrl . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'protected' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'extensions' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'facebook');

require_once (Yii::app()->baseUrl . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'protected' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'extensions' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'facebook' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');

require_once (Yii::app()->baseUrl . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'protected' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'extensions' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'facebook' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Facebook' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'FacebookSession.php');

and for creating object

$session = new Facebook\FacebookSession($access_token);

Answer (score 0):

Nitin
    Just Copy the zip file of your extnsion into your protected/extension directory and then extract that zip file to get .php file, try this..