# Facebook SDK PHP

Tags: php, facebook, yii, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have need your help about Facebook SDK with PHP in Yii Framework. But when I put all file in php-sdk which download from developer.facebook.com into portected/vendor and config in config/main.php.
In file I use code:

> require_once (Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php');
>
> use Facebook\FacebookSession;
>   use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
>   use Facebook\GraphUser;
>   use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
>   use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

But when I use:
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(api_key,api_secret);

It shown me an error:

> Class Facebook FacebookSession not found in......

Can you help me about this error.Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

Please include all class files.

```
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/facebook-php-sdk/autoload.php';       
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php';
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php';
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php';
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php';
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php';
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/vendors/facebook-php-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499982/yii-import-extension-not-finding-class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try this :

```
session_start();
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', './facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/');
require_once("./facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php");

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
```

just only use "./facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php" in your project

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?